# Why is WeightedData slow?

Tags: performance-tuning, histograms

I have been using `WeightedData` with `Histogram`, `HistogramList`, `DensityHistogram`, `HistogramDistribution` and `SmoothKernelDistribution`, with 1D and 2D data, and have noticed that those functions are much slower when the same data is represented with `WeightedData` instead of an unweighted data list.

This can be seen here:

```
d=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],10^5];
w=ConstantArray[1,Length[d]];
wd=WeightedData[d,w];
HistogramList[d,{.1}]//Timing//First
HistogramList[wd,{.1}]//Timing//First
```

The unweighted histogram takes 0.05s and the weighted one takes 3.4s.

What makes these functions be slower with `WeightedData`?

Comment: Wow, that's bad performance. This is a question for support! I can hardly imagine any _good_ reason for this.

Comment: Yeah. Most of my use has been with SmoothKernelDistribution, and it would take about 20 minutes for a 2D dataset of about 20000 weighted entries. I was blaming already SmoothKernelDistribution for being so slow. It never crossed my mind that the weighted data wouldn't be faster than the plain full dataset.

Comment: I sent Wolfram a report about the issue. I'll post here any update.